# DataTable sorting is not working after ajax replace data in table

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatable

**I have a DataTable in my JSP page. Its table data will replace after an ajax call. But after successfully ajax call table is not sorting.

Here is the jquery with Ajax call.

```js
$(document).on('click','#Search',function (e){
    $('#datatable').DataTable().destroy();
    $('#datatable').DataTable({          
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: {  
            url:'<%=contextPath%>/show/find/patient',
            headers: {                                                  
                'Authorization':'${sessionScope.token}'
            },                   
            data:{
                "assignedMemberId": $("#assignedMemberId").val(),
                "ssnLast4" : $("#ssnLast4").val()
            },
            type:'GET',
            success:function(data){
                console.log(data);
                $('#patientDetails').html(data);  
            },
      error:function(e){
          console.log(e)
            }   
        }       
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="patientDetails">
    <table id="datatable" class="table table-bordered dttble">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Ticket</th>
                <th scope="col">CP</th>
                <th scope="col">First Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Middle Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Enrolled On</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>         
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

What I am missing? Any suggestion will be very helpful.

Comment: Do you know what your call is actually returining on the ajax requrest? Should this not be updating an iframe

Comment: Ajax call replaces the whole table which comes from java side as buffer.append.

Comment: Do you have any control over the endpoint to order the results (before your retrieve them). Ths sounds like tyou need to make a second call the the endpoint (to order the results). Then empty the container and reappend them to the container.

Comment: Actually I am not doing anything in order to sort the result. The DataTable jquery function does the sorting functionality.

Comment: Have you looked at this [link](https://datatables.net/reference/api/order())